# Read Array Object from WSDL XML with namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing, wsdl, nusoap

I am sending array of objects in XML Soap response from my java code to php in my project using WSDL.

I want to store values in php for my project.

I tried many ways but couldn't able to find how to parse my xml and read values. I am not export in xml area.

Please anyone help me for read my values from values.

### My SOAP Response Body:

```
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" \xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:body>

<getactualtimerequestresponse xmlns="http://impl.sample.com">
        <getactualtimereturn>.
            <ns1:projectlist xmlns:ns1="http://response.sample.com">
                <item>
                    <ns2:userid xmlns:ns2="http://request.sample.com">4</ns2:userid>
                    <ns3:username xmlns:ns3="http://request.sample.com">Manoj Arun</ns3:username>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <ns5:userid xmlns:ns5="http://request.sample.com">5</ns5:userid>
                    <ns6:username xmlns:ns6="http://request.sample.com">Sethu Raman</ns6:username>
                </item>
            </ns1:projectlist>              
            <ns10:message xsi:nil="true" xmlns:ns10="http://response.sample.com"></ns10:message>
        </getactualtimereturn>
    </getactualtimerequestresponse>
</soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>
```

projectList is my object created in java.

In PHP:

I tried to read like below but i didn't got anything.

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//ns:projectList') as $header)
{
    foreach($header->item as $userIds)
    {
         echo $userIds->xpath('//ns:userId');
    }                       
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $client = new SoapClient('http://url.com?wsdl');
 $params = array(Java arg => php value);
 $result = $client->Function( $parms );
 print_r($result);
```